# executing shell scripts in java script or trigger scanner from browser

Tags: java, javascript, linux, bash, shell

I have one shell script for scanning documents from scanner(hardware).

Shell scripts were stored in each client system.

Suppose client scans application means i have to run that shell script and store scanned application in server.

I am using Html, JavaScript and servlets.

If I run shell script from servlet, it will execute shell script in a server.

I want to execute shell script from client system.

I think if we used JavaScript we can do this. Is there any way to do this?

Other then shell script how can we trigger scanner in browser ?

Comment: As said many times here and all around the web. **No, you can't.** If it was possible then we all had a **BIG security issue**.

Comment: http://people.w3.org/~dom/archives/2005/09/integrating-a-new-uris-scheme-handler-to-gnome-and-firefox/

Comment: Ok.Is there any way to trigger scanner from browser?

Comment: Yes, epascarello's link but each client must be **manually and explictly configured**.

Comment: You can not execute server side script from a client side.

Comment: @JeevanRoydsouza: JavaScript doesn't have access to the client's system, nor does it come with IO capabilities out of the box. If it did, imagine how unsafe the web would be

Comment: @Samy i want to execute client side script..Each cliend will have scanner running script

Comment: @Adriano Ok i will go through that link.

Comment: @JeevanRoydsouza : Its not possible at all. Client i meant was browser. You can not invoke shell script remotely. If possible try opening up a terminal/bash from javascript which might give you more clearity.

Comment: @Samy Java scripts wont allow to execute client scripts?

Answer (score 1):

JS cannot interact with client OS or File system (except in limited case as File upload) for obvious security issues.

The only way to do this with webbrowser is to install an ActiveX or DLL on client side that will be able to start your client script. But this is browser specific (and probably Windows specific...).

Maybe you can make the user download the script and then give explanations to execute it himself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java Web Start or a signed applet. However, this requires the user to install Java.