# How to execute shell script from Java applet

Tags: java, applet

I want to access a document scanner on client's side so I have created a shell script to perform this action. Is there any way to execute it through a browser applet? Is there a way to make it work on Fedora 18 OS that will allow me to install a plugin like `twain`? This how I call my script currently:

```
String[] cmd = {"sh test.sh", "/Path/to my/resource file"};
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd)
```

Comment: [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20704711/executing-shell-scripts-in-java-script-or-trigger-scanner-from-browser) this gives answer for your question....

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java Web Start or a signed applet.